# Classification Loss result is either too small or too big as epoch get higher

Tags: neural-networks, classification, image-processing

I am doing some experiments for classifying color using BCElogitLoss on Pytorch. The label that I have are (not red-red, not blue-blue , not green -green) and the inputs are images. So when I start the training, it starts with a normal range of loss between 0-1 but after some epoch it become either very large like 800000 loss or become very small like 1.6 e-6. Is this kind of thing normal? Because what I know, loss should be between 0-1. For the pre-processing I didn't do normalization except from the Pytorch build-in which automatically normalize the image into 0-1, I read other code they tend to normalize it again into -1 to 1 but I find this affect badly on my other losses so I didn't use it. So maybe someone can give me explanation about this problem that I had. In case if you need the model architecture, I can post it but it will be quite complicated to see. Thank you

Comment: What does it mean for a loss to be "too small"? Losses are minimized, so if the loss is small, that sounds like evidence that things are working correctly.

Comment: I was thinking that it should be on some range like from 0 to 1 only. So those loss that I mention is still considered normal?

Comment: BCElogiLoss is minimized at 0, and 1.6e-6 is pretty close to machine eps for single-precision floats. So that seems to be going well. On the other hand, wildly swinging between very large and very small loss values is a symptom of having too large a learning rate.